# Efeito mouseover td com jquery ou css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, front-end

Como fazer para quando eu passar o mouse em cima da minha `td`, mostrar nela o ícone de edição?

Obs: Meu código não funciona:

jQuery Event:

```
$(".editableSpan").mouseover(function(){
    $("#tdEditable").append("<span id='widthSource'></span><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>");
});
```

HTML:

```
<td id="tdEditable" class="editableSpan"><span id="widthSource"></span></td>
```

Gostaria que quando o evento for `hover` em qualquer td da minha table ele mostre o ícone de editar alinhado a direita.

Comment: Não sei se percebí a pergunta bem... é isto que procuras? --> http://jsfiddle.net/ndo9psme/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja se esse serve.

```js
$( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>" ) );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).find( ".fa" ).remove();
  }
);
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.fa{
   float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Ótima resposta